# JQuery: Random rotation and shift of multiple div-container

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to put some div-container on each other? They should also be rotated and shifted randomly a few degrees/a few pixel in all dimensions. As a result there should be a div-container on top; all other container should be placed below that - rotated and shifted a little bit, so they look as a random, messy stack of paper

For rotation I'm using this script:

```
$(".exp").each( function() {
  var rNum = (Math.random()*4)-2;  
  $(this).css( {   
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'2deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'2deg)'  
  } );  
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m9XHQ/

How can I do the shift in a same way?
How can I put the elements onto each other (css)?

**Edit:**

I want to achieve something like this: http://ieh.de/stack.png
That's why I need the "shifting"-function. The papers in that example aren't just rotated... (Rotation is only a few degrees)

Comment: Forcefully stacking elements will likely require absolute positioning, you can probably set a random + or - x and y position for the divs in the same way you set rotation and have them stack that way

Comment: Are you lookin for something like: http://jsfiddle.net/m9XHQ/7/

Comment: Even More beautiful: http://jsfiddle.net/m9XHQ/8/

Comment: Looks nice. But what about shifting? Please have a look at the example...

Answer (score 2):

You can position them to sit on top of each other with absolute positioning (this looks a little weird because of the current background coloring). In order to do this and still allowing positing of the group of elements, I added a wrapper div to contain them all that can then be positioned on your page without affecting the stack of paper.

Testing your fiddle with multiple colors looks like you might want more rotation to achieve the effect you are looking for.

I modified your CSS to be:

```
.exp { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: red; 
    margin: 5px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="exp"></div>
    <div class="exp"></div>
    <div class="exp"></div>
    <div class="exp"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `#wrapper`. +1

Comment: The only reason I added the wrapper is to facilitate further placement of the div's on the page. Without the wrapper, if you try to position or move any of the other elements, you can run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

Changed up the html a bit to make it more apparent, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9XHQ/6/
As per my comment:

HTML

```
<div style="background-color: red;" class="exp"></div>
<div style="background-color: blue;" class="exp"></div>
<div style="background-color: green;" class="exp"></div>
<div style="background-color: purple;" class="exp"></div>
```

CSS

```
.exp { width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute;  margin: 5px;  }
```

Javascript

```
$(".exp").each( function() {
  var rNum = (Math.random()*4)-2;
    var x = (Math.random()*10)-5;
    var y = (Math.random()*10)-5;
  $(this).css( {   
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'2deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'2deg)',
      'top': x,
      'left': y

  } );  
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code you'll create 5 divs in absolute position on body [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/Zaf4E/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        var rotate=Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        $('<div class="dinamic"></div>').css({ 
         '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)',
         WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)',
         'transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)',
        }).appendTo('body')
    }
})
</script>
```

with this other script [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/4xBy2/4/) you can get rndom color for divs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        var rotate=Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        var color = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
        console.log(color)
        $('<div class="dinamic"></div>').css({ 
         '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)',
         WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)',
         'transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)',
         'background-color':color
        }).appendTo('body')
    }
})
</script>
```